# Docker container not picking up CSS file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, cloud

I have a docker-compose file as follows:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  signup:
    container_name: signup
    build: .
    ports:
     - "88:80"
    image: sgc-signup:Dockerfile
    networks:
      - test
    restart: always
networks:
    test:
      external:
        name: test
```

And a docker file of:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
```

The working directory for this container is:

```
   sgc-signup
      src
         footer.php
         functions.php
         index.php
         navbar.php
         styling.css
      docker-compose.yml
      Dockerfile
```

The console when i run the container locally returns the following error regarding styling .css:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Almost identical code has worked in another container for signin.

I have tried clearing the cache as well as docker-compose up --build and a couple of similar solutions found on stack overflow with no joy so far.

Comment: if you open a shell in the container, do you see the file in there? what is the exact path where your app looks for the css file? this doesn't look like a docker issue, more like an application issue

Comment: yea its visible in git bash. exact path is /c/Users/public/sgc_40054873/sgc-signup/src/styling.css

Comment: In the container. Not on host.